# Eclipse CDT: Shortcut to switch between .h and .cpp?

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt

In Eclipse, is there a keyboard shortcut for switching the editor view from viewing a .cpp file to a corresponding .h file, and vice versa?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> is the default shortcut.
You can change it in Window → Preferences → General → Keys: **Toggle Source/Header**

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me, and "Toggle Source/Header" is not one of the options in the keys dialog :( I think my Eclipse installation is broken..

Comment: What version are you using? Are you sure CDT is installed?

Comment: Yep - My eclipse is very very broken. Turns out an update failed and I can't revert. Time to nuke it and reinstall.

Answer (score 5):

There is a shortcut: Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd>